# Build Failure for JDT Core with Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to build the JDT Core library with maven.  I downloaded the git repository and in that folder I issued:  `mvn -P build-individual-bundles package`

I get the error below after a few minutes.  Any ideas?  TIA!

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5:04.943s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 24 08:36:51 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 82M/455M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:0.21.0:compile (default-compile) on project org.eclipse.jdt.annotation: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] F:\Workspace\git\eclipse-jdt-core\org.eclipse.jdt.annotation\src\org\eclipse\jdt\annotation\NonNull.java:[14]
[ERROR] import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE_USE;
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The import java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE_USE cannot be resolved
[ERROR] F:\Workspace\git\eclipse-jdt-core\org.eclipse.jdt.annotation\src\org\eclipse\jdt\annotation\NonNull.java:[52]
[ERROR] @Target({ TYPE_USE })
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] TYPE_USE cannot be resolved to a variable
[ERROR] F:\Workspace\git\eclipse-jdt-core\org.eclipse.jdt.annotation\src\org\eclipse\jdt\annotation\Nullable.java:[14]
[ERROR] import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE_USE;
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The import java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE_USE cannot be resolved
[ERROR] F:\Workspace\git\eclipse-jdt-core\org.eclipse.jdt.annotation\src\org\eclipse\jdt\annotation\Nullable.java:[43]
[ERROR] @Target({ TYPE_USE })
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] TYPE_USE cannot be resolved to a variable
[ERROR] 4 problems (4 errors)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.eclipse.jdt.annotation
```

Version information:

```
F:\Workspace\git\eclipse-jdt-core>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 08:22:22-0700)
Maven home: C:\Apps\Java\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_67, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Apps\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: @greg-449 - how did you indent the snippets so easily?  is it possible to do online here on StackOverflow or did you use a text editor like SublimeText?

Comment: Just select the text and click the '{}' tool to indent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it needs to be compiled with Java 8.

`java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE_USE` is new in Java 8.